# LWC design attributes doesn't work in the Community with Anonymous User

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, design-attributes

Did someone try to use LWC in Communities?

I created component to dynamically render Knowledge articles based on provided Topic by passing Topic.Name as Design Attribute.

It works in Builder, but when I publish Community and try to debug values for the design parameter it always returns null.

```xml
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="topic" type="String" default="test"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

```
    @api
    topic = '';

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log(`topic = ${this.topic}`);
    }
```

Any advice is appreciated because I don't really want to update everything with Aura components as a wrapper.

**EDIT:**
The issue is that topic doesn't have the correct value when I set it in Community Builder.
[image]

Comment: Could you try {!recordName}? Do your guest users have the appropriate permissions to view the topic?

Comment: It is working as expected and showing values after publishing.

Comment: @kenan Problem is that I have in console 'topic = '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what was the issue.

I raised the case, updated my code to aura and when I actually needed to present the issue to the support - LWC started to work.

Weird staff

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce finally fixed the issue and you can use variables in LWC now